# Clear input field without reloading of the page

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a input field where a user enters in a name at the end of a quiz and i have tried various methods of clearing the field. The page cannot re-load as the user is able to restart a quiz.

Here is my HTML:

```
    <div class="js-quiz-submit">
    <input type="text" class="js-name" placeholder="Please Enter Your Name"/>
    <input type="button" class="js-submit" value="Submit"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: What did you try already? Paste your code into the question, tell whats going wrong and what you try to accomplish.

Comment: I tried this code initially: document.getElementById("myForm").reset(); the submit field gets hidden aftet the user hits submit, but then if i restart the form at the end of the quiz the input field appears again with the name prefilled in. I would like to have to it clear the name after the user hits submit and the form field gets hidden

Answer (score 1):

If your input field is in a form say `#quiz-form`, then you can clear the fields of form as follows:

```
var form = document.querySelector('#quiz-form');
form.reset();
```

Comment: Warning! - This will reset the entire form. While this may be what you wanna do I was just making it clear that's what it does.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the better way will be :

```
document.querySelector(".js-name").value = "";
```

Comment: I modified my js file with this based on the notes above:                   
const form = document.querySelector(".js-name").value = "";
form.reset(); I was not able to clear the form.

Comment: I also have this above in the js file to hide the form once the user hits submit, could this be causing the clear to not work? $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".js-submit").click(function(){
        $(".js-quiz-submit").hide();
    });
});

Comment: What did you want exactly ? clear the `.js-name` field ? after submitting the form ? Can you share your code ?

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
<div class="js-quiz-submit">
  <input type="text" id="js-name" class="js-name" placeholder="Please Enter Your Name"/>
  <input type="button" class="js-submit" value="Submit"/>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('js-name').value='';
```